# Exicute python script in Forms ( oracle forms builder)

Tags: python, sql, oracle, forms, plsql

Hey I am working on a project , that requires to execute a python script when user press a button on Forms ( oracal forms builder) . I did try to solve the problem (with the Help of you know who ) , did not worked.
Anyone have experience in this field?-Thank you in advance

```
DECLARE
  cmd VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  cmd := 'python /path/to/your/script.py';
  HOST(cmd);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Nothing

Comment: The main problem is where that script resides. It should reside on the app server where the forms application runs, on which python has to be also installed. Don't count on having Forms 11 or later execute a python script on the client computer running the Forms applet.